# Run ffmpeg2theora convert in the background

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to batch convert few files in a folder using ffmpeg2theora.

```
for filename in $(pwd)/*
    do
    ffmpeg2theora -v 6 -a 5 $filename && mv $filename finished/
    done;
```

But now the code waits for one video to finish before converting another one. How do i convert all videos at the same time in the background ? Its giving me verbose output also which i dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a single ampersand to the end of the command to start it in the background. To redirect output into nirvana, you can use `> /dev/null`

```
ffmpeg2theora -v 6 -a 5 $filename > /dev/null 2>&1  && mv $filename finished/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I still see the output on the screen, but this converts all the videos at the same time. And the script is not quiting after all the operations are over.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Had to add `> /dev/null` to the first command, too.

Comment: Still gives partial verbose output, can you please try the code ?Just cd into a folder with 2 ~ 3 tiny videos and run this code in the folder..